# Intellij Java Webstart Basics

Tags: intellij-idea, deployment, java-web-start

My question is *"How do you get a Java Web Start project started in the IntelliJ IDEA IDE?"*

### First Attempt

IntelliJ's default JavaFX Project Template includes an artifact configuration that (when the *native bundle* is set to `exe`) seems to set you up to deploy your application using Java Webstart (or at least test it on your machine).

Once you `Build Artifacts`, it gives you a `.jnlp` file, as well as an HTML file containing a link to run the `.jnlp` file.

[image: Artifact List]

Yet! With even the most basic application, it's not getting off the ground.

In order to provide exact detail, I'll include the code for the HTML and `.jnlp` files as well as a video that shows what happens.

- [HTML File](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/830c04a3f3e58478e542ab1c138b5a04)
- [`.jnlp` File](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a66288b248d5d5783a99e86c731f83e4)
- [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yd4v2mhCXfs)

---

### Progress

#### Swing on Tomcat

- I was able to successfully launch a *Swing* application from the local Tomcat server I just installed using some help from [a tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/web-start/java-web-start-getting-started/)—confusingly, using the similar steps of *jarring*, *signing*, and *putting on webserver* with a *JavaFX* application results in a [stupid blocked window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6mYz.png) even though the file is [included in the Exception Site List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6mYz.png).

  - This makes me wonder if it's a signing issue. (I signed the jar with a homemade keystore, but notably without certificate or timestamp—this caused no problems with *Swing*; could it be causing problems with *JavaFX*? If I need a more-legitimate certificate and timestamp, how do I get them?)

---

Surely I'm missing something. What other steps need to be taken to deploy a JavaFX application using *Webstart*? Is anyone willing to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Did you try to open HTML locally and not from the web server?

Comment: I hope you'll excuse my noob-hood. I've never server-ed. I was under the impression that the link was somehow using my computer as a webserver because it said `localhost:63342`. Here's [a picture.](https://i.imgur.com/JqpW5jx.png)

Comment: That is built-in web server, try opening the file instead.

Comment: Opening the `.jnlp` file directly resulted in this [_Java Application Blocked_ Dialog](https://i.imgur.com/1A9dcEs.png)

Comment: You either need to adjust the security settings or make it so that the jar is also loaded from the web server instead of the `file://` protocol.

Comment: I just included the HTML and `.jnlp` files. Do those shed any light on anything?

Comment: What happens is that you download and open the `.jnlp` file from the local drive, this file has a reference to the `.jar` file in the same location where `.jnlp` resides, Java tries to load the `.jar` file from the directory where `.jnlp` was saved (a temp directory). Obviously, there is no any `.jar` there. Check [the manual here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/running.html). `Notepad.jnlp` file has `codebase` specified, so the `.jar` is loaded from `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/deployment/NotepadJWSProject/Notepad.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I put a copy of the `.jar` where the `.jnlp` file got downloaded to, and I ran it. It found the `.jar`, but it has the same security issue. I've never signed a jar, but something tells me that's what needs to happen. Any advice about that direction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141444/discussion-between-crazycoder-and-brad-turek).